# Is noLoop stopping execution of draw?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, processing

This is my first post here, so I apologize if I'm making any mistakes.

I recently started to study Processing in Python mode and I'm trying to develop a code that, after selecting an image from your computer, reads the colors and inserts them in a list. The final idea is to calculate the percentage of certain colors in the image. For this I am using the following code:

```
img = None
tam=5
cores_img = []


def setup():
    size (500, 500)
    selectInput(u"Escolha a ilustração para leitura de cores", "adicionar_imagens")
    noLoop()

def adicionar_imagens(selection):
    global img
    if selection == None:
        print(u"Seleção cancelada")
    else:
        print(u"Você selecionou " + selection.getAbsolutePath())
        img = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath())
                
def draw():
    if img is not None:
        image (img, 0, 0)
        for xg in range(0, img.width, tam):
            x = map(xg, 0, img.width, 0, img.width)
            for yg in range(0, img.height, tam):
                y = map(yg, 0, img.height, 0, img.height)
                cor = img.get(int(x), int(y))
                cores_img.append(cor)
                print (cores_img)
```

I'm using noLoop() so that the colors are added only once to the list. However, it seems that the draw is not running. It performs the setup actions, but when the image is selected, nothing happens. There is also no error message.

I'm completely lost about what might be happening. If anyone has any ideas and can help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: what is the end goal you're trying to achieve ? (it looks like you're trying to sparsely sample colours, as if the image is downsampled: where would these coloured be used ?)

Comment: The final idea is to use the list to calculate the percentage of certain colors in an illustration, with a determined color palette.

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`noLoop()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/noLoop.html) indeed stops the `draw()` loop from running, which means by the time you've selected and image nothing yould happen.

You can however manually call `draw()` (or [`redraw()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/redraw.html)) once the image is loaded:

```
img = None
tam=5
cores_img = []


def setup():
    size (500, 500)
    selectInput(u"Escolha a ilustração para leitura de cores", "adicionar_imagens")
    noLoop()

def adicionar_imagens(selection):
    global img
    if selection == None:
        print(u"Seleção cancelada")
    else:
        print(u"Você selecionou " + selection.getAbsolutePath())
        img = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath())
        redraw()
                
def draw():
    if img is not None:
        image (img, 0, 0)
        for xg in range(0, img.width, tam):
            x = map(xg, 0, img.width, 0, img.width)
            for yg in range(0, img.height, tam):
                y = map(yg, 0, img.height, 0, img.height)
                cor = img.get(int(x), int(y))
                cores_img.append(cor)
                print (cores_img)
```

You should pay attention to a few details:

- As the reference mentions, calling [get()](https://py.processing.org/reference/get.html) is slow: `pixels[x + y * width]` is faster (just remember to call `loadPixels()` if the array doesn't look right)
- PImage already has a `pixels` array: calling `img.resize(img.width / tam, img .height / tam)` should downsample the image so you can read the same list
- `x = map(xg, 0, img.width, 0, img.width)` (and similarly `y`) maps from one range to the same range which has no effect

e.g.

```
img = None
tam=5
cores_img = None


def setup():
    size (500, 500)
    selectInput(u"Escolha a ilustração para leitura de cores", "adicionar_imagens")
    noLoop()

def adicionar_imagens(selection):
    global img, cores_img
    if selection == None:
        print(u"Seleção cancelada")
    else:
        print(u"Você selecionou " + selection.getAbsolutePath())
        img = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath())
        print("total pixels",len(img.pixels))
        img.resize(img.width / tam, img.height / tam);
        cores_img = list(img.pixels)
        print("resized pixels",len(img.pixels))
        print(cores_img)
                
def draw():
    pass
```

**Update**

> I thought that calling noLoop on setup would make draw run once. Still
> it won't print the image... I'm calling 'image (img, 0, 0)' at the end
> of 'else', on 'def adicionar_imagens (selection)'. Should I call it
> somewhere else?

- think of `adicionar_imagens` time-wise, running separate to `setup()` and `draw()`
- you are right, `draw()` should be called once (because of `noLoop()`), however it's called as soon as `setup()` completes but not later (as navigating the file system, selecting a file and confirming takes time)
- `draw()` would need to be forced to run again after the image was loaded

Here's an updated snippet:

```
img = None
# optional: potentially useful for debugging
img_resized = None
tam=5
cores_img = None


def setup():
    size (500, 500)
    selectInput(u"Escolha a ilustração para leitura de cores", "adicionar_imagens")
    noLoop()

def adicionar_imagens(selection):
    global img, img_resized, cores_img
    if selection == None:
        print(u"Seleção cancelada")
    else:
        print(u"Você selecionou " + selection.getAbsolutePath())
        img = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath())
        # make a copy of the original image (to keep it intact)
        img_resized = img.get()
        # resize
        img_resized.resize(img.width / tam, img.height / tam)
        # convert pixels array to python list
        cores_img = list(img.pixels)
        # force redraw
        redraw()
        # print data
        print("total pixels",len(img.pixels))
        print("resized pixels",len(img.pixels))
        # print(cores_img)

def draw():
    print("draw called " + str(millis()) + "ms after sketch started")
    # if an img was selected and loaded, display it 
    if(img != None):
        image(img, 0, 0)
    # optionally display resized image
    if(img_resized != None):
        image(img_resized, 0, 0)
```

Here are a couple of notes that may be helpful:

- each pixel in the list is a 24 bit ARGB colour (e.g. all channels are stored in a single value). if you need individual colour channels remember you have functions like [`red()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/red.html), [`green()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/green.html), [`blue()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/blue.html) available. (Also if that gets slow notice the example include faster versions using bit shifting and masking)
- the [Histogram example](https://processing.org/examples/histogram.html) could be helpful. You would need to port from Java to Python syntax and use 3 histograms (one for each colour channel), however the principle of counting intensities is nicely illustrated

[image: histogram overlaid on image]

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I thought that calling noLoop on setup would make draw run once. Still it won't print the image... I'm calling 'image (img, 0, 0)' at the end of 'else', on 'def adicionar_imagens (selection)'. Should I call it somewhere else?

Comment: @HelenaSulzbeck see the update above. Could you expand on the predetermined color palette part ?

Comment: Great answer, as always. I can always tell I'm reading a George answer before I get to the bottom and actually see your name.